# Accessing elements of a cv::Mat with at<float>(i, j). Is it (x,y) or (row,col)?

Tags: c++, opencv

When we access specific elements of a `cv::Mat` structure, we can use `mat.at<float>(i,j)` to access the element at position `i, j`.  What is not immediately clear, however, whether `i, j` refers to the `x, y` coordinate in the matrix, or the ith row and the jth column.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

OpenCV, like may other libraries, treat matrices (and images) in row-major order. That means every access is defined as `(row, column)`.

Notable exceptions from this general rule are Matlab and Eigen libraries.

Comment: It's a bit long a time since I worked with MATLAB, but I doubt it uses [column,row], I would remember such a mathematical inconsistency.

Comment: Wikipedia stands by me. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order#Column-major_order

Comment: It may be stored in column-major order internally, but the indexing is done in standard mathematical (row,col) order and matrices are even specified in row-major order. Have you even worked with MATLAB for at least 1 minute or is it only Wikipedia that's on your side? Keep in mind that the question was about indexing and not about storage. Those may coincide, but they needn't, at least when there's an additional abstraction layer in between.

Comment: I am old Matlab guy. And many times I was frustrated that everything in matlab has to be converted from (x, y) to (y, x) in C++

Comment: So you use A(3,1) to get the element in the third column of the first row? I doubt that, or this must indeed be a really old MATLAB version.

Comment: I am sorry to dissapoint you, but this is the way Matlab works. And it is the same from Matlab 6.0 (my first, early in 2005) to the latest version I am working with now. But SO says we should limit comments here.

Comment: Let's see what the MathWorks people say: http://www.mathworks.de/company/newsletters/articles/Matrix-Indexing-in-MATLAB/matrix.html. Yes, when using linear indexing it's indeed column-major, but this question was about (i,j)-indexing (and neither was it about storage).

Comment: @vasile In the old C API, we have cvSetReal2D(mat, i, j, value);.  Was the i,j in this also (row, col)?  Is it the same idea?

Comment: Here http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html?highlight=cvsetreal2d#setreal-d it says this func keeps the same access rules

Comment: Just adding some more info to the discussion about Opencv vs Matlab: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25644503/1403372

Comment: Note that this answer is incorrect as it stands and contains incorrect misleading information. I've edited (it's in peer review) but also posted a correct version below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42327350/1345959

Comment: @Ela782: Of course, you're right that there's a distinction between access order (the API) and storage order (an implementation detail), but I don't think it's a good idea to edit other people's answers, especially not to change their meaning. Post your own answer (which you have done) and try to redirect people to it.

Comment: @pyon: Yep, after some pondering and review-feedback I definitely agree. Thanks for posting. It's just so hard to see this as the accepted answer ;-) Especially as this pops up high in Google search results.

Comment: Maybe @Chris can change any of the other answers as the accepted one? (if that's still possible after 6 years)

Comment: It did mislead and I upvated it without experimentation, but then I realize the answer below is the correct one.

Comment: @Sam The Wikipedia link you posted does not support what you wrote in your answer. There is an example of column major order in Fortran on that Wikipedia page that clearly shows a row-first _indexing_. The part of your answer that is wrong is "That means access is defined as `(row, column)`"; this is not what row-major order means. Row-major / column-major order is about memory layout, not indexing.

Answer (score 57):

OpenCV, like many other libraries, treat matrix **access** in row-major order. That means every access is defined as `(row, column)`. Note that if you're working with x and y coordinates of an image, this becomes `(y, x)`, if `y` is your vertical axis.

Most matrix libraries are the same in that regards, the access is `(row, col)` as well in, for example, Matlab or Eigen (a C++ matrix library).

Where these applications and libraries do differ however is how the data is actually **stored** in memory. OpenCV stores the data in row-major order in memory (i.e. the rows come first), while for example Matlab stores the data in column-major order in memory. But if you're just a user of these libraries, and accessing the data via a `(row, col)` accessor, you'll never actually see this difference in **memory storage order**.

Comment: Note that in the Eigen library, there is an optional template argument `Options` to specify the **storage** order which specifies how the data should/will be stored in the memory. Its values can be `ColMajor` or `RowMajor`. If the **storage** order is not specified, Eigen defaults to **storing** the data in **column-major**.  However, in either case, matrix **access** is still defined as **`(row, col)`** i.e. **row-major** Source: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStorageOrders.html

Comment: @Milan Good point, and a great extension to my answer!

Answer (score 35):

So OpenCV handles this a bit strange. OpenCV stores the Mat in row major order, but addressing it over the methood Mat::at() falsely suggests column major order. I think the Opencv documentation is misleading in this case. I had to write this testcase to make sure for myself.

```
cv::Mat m(3,3,CV_32FC1,0.0f);
m.at<float>(1,0) = 2;
cout << m << endl;
```

So addressing is done with Mat::at(y,x) :

> [0, 0, 0; 
>    2, 0, 0; 
>    0, 0, 0]

But raw pointer access reveals that it is actually stored row major, e.g. the "2" is in the 4th position. If it were stored in column major order, it would be in the 2nd position.

```
float* mp = &m.at<float>(0);
for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
    cout << mp[i] << " ";
```

> > 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0

As a side remark: Matlab stores and addresses a matrix in column major order. It might be annoying, but at least it is consistent.

Comment: really nice; It is an clearly example to depend on an abstraction, not on an implementation.

Comment: I believe that OpenCV addressing method follows the Math terminology for matrices, rows x cols, so you have Mat::at(row, col).

Comment: This answer also contains some false information. Matrix access in OpenCV is row-first too (e.g. `Mat::at(row, col)`). It is (row, col) in Matlab too. The difference between OpenCV and Matlab is memory storage order, but this is completely independent from accessing the matrices with `(row, col)`. See my answer below for more details.

Comment: @Ela782: Indeed the access order and storage order are two separate things (as commented in the other answer). However, I would argue that answer does **not** provide false information. It merely points out that one might be easily confused (e.g. when coming from Matlab) by having row-major storage order and using an access API with the `(row, col)` convention. At least it confused me back in the day, because I assumed the first parameter to be the "major storage dimension".

Comment: If that weren't confusing enough, `cv::Point` by convention is constructed (x, y). So: `m.at(y, x)` is the same as `m.at(Point(x, y))`.

Answer (score 13):

From what I've read in the documentation, it's `at(y, x)` (i.e. `row, col`).

Answer (score 11):

Since `cv::Mat` is actually a general matrix, with images being just a special case, it follows matrix indexing and therefore the row (`y`) comes before the column (`x`):

```
mat.at(i, j) = mat.at(row, col) = mat.at(y, x)
```