# circle detection fail after convert buffered image to Mat

Tags: java, opencv, javacv, hough-transform

i'm new to opencv and use `opencv3` .I'm trying to detect circles using hough-transform .i have [this code](http://pastebin.com/pTjpwWxJ) which read image from a file and detect circles then write it to a file.this works fine .here is the original [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otEi2.jpg) and here is the [detected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nm5zN.jpg) one.

but i want to detect circles in a buffered image .so i used a method to convert buffered image to Mat object .then what happened is circle detection failed and image has been resized .also brightness has reduce too much.this is [failed one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Il0TM.jpg).

here is the code i used to convert buffered image to mat ( taken from the stackoverflow answer)

```
public Mat bufferedImageToMat(BufferedImage bi) {
    byte[] pixels = ((DataBufferByte) bi.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    Mat mat = new Mat(bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
    mat.put(0, 0, pixels);
    return mat;
}
```

i think problem is in above method.
this is code line `47` and `48`.

```
Mat source = Imgcodecs.imread(circleimage, Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
//Mat source = bufferedImageToMat(bi);
```

if i use 1st one(directly read from image) code works .but if i use 2nd one circle detection fail.

can you see a problem in this method ? thanks

Comment: in C++ syntax Mat constructor uses the parameters in different order: `Mat(rows, cols, type)`, probably that's same for java syntax? Please try `new Mat(bi.getHeight(), bi.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC3);`

Comment: @Micka ohh yeah you are right .tnx you so much.post it as answer plz.it works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OpenCV, images are represented by matrices, whose constructors use number of `rows` before number of `columns`, so you should use

```
Mat mat = new Mat(bi.getHeight(), bi.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
```

I've tried to explain the reason in [OpenCV Point(x,y) represent (column,row) or (row,column)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25642532/opencv-pointx-y-represent-column-row-or-row-column/25644503#25644503) if you would like to know more about it.

Comment: That is a very nice answer. Saving that as target for duplicates :D