# c++ opencv access pixel value incorrect

Tags: c++, opencv

I got some problem when I use img.at(y,x) to access pixel value in C++, here is my code:

```
   int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    Mat image;
    image = imread("a.jpg",-1);   
 int a;
  for(int x = 0; x<image.rows;x++)
    {
      cout<<endl;
      for(int y = 0; y< image.cols; y++)
      {
       a = (int)image.at<uchar>(y,x);
       if(a>200)
       {
       cout<<"1 ";
       }else{
       cout<<a<<" ";
       }
      }
    }
}
```

so the function is going to iterate all pixel then if it is 255 print 1, rest remains.

Here is the a.jpg image:
[image]

but it prints out like that

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 7 0 0 7 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 3 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 0 2 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 2 0 5 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 2 0 2 0 1 1 0 2 0 2 0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 2 0 2 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 2 0 3 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 2 0 0 0 2 0 2 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 2 0 0 2 2 0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 1 1 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 2 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 1 0 2 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 1 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 7 0 0 7 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 5 0 2 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 2 0 5 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 2 0 2 0 1 1 0 2 0 2 0 0 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 2 0 2 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 2 0 3 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 2 0 0 0 2 0 2 0 0 0 0
```

does anyone know the reason? I have tried 8bit jpg, 16 bit tiff, png, output are all pretty weird, which should be image shape(white part)

it works fine on python that is the most weird thing

any help appreciated!

Comment: Convert image to greyscale, or load it as greyscale first.

Comment: You mixed up x and y like Kochoba mentioned in his snswer. Try `a = (int)image.at<uchar>(x,y)` and look at the [opencv tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html#howtoscanimagesopencv) how to efficiently loop over a mat.

Comment: @PSchn Thanks a lot! that is truly helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you have set x to be row and y to be column. You have to interchange the variables when you are reading from the matrix. This formulation is row order and not column order.

```
a = (int)image.at<uchar>(x,y);
```

You can also read the following SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25642532/opencv-pointx-y-represent-column-row-or-row-column) about the confusion between row order and column order.

Comment: That is a great help! Thanks a lot! jpg image is working fine, but some other problem still remaining in tif and png, I will ask a new question, and truly thank!

Answer (score 0):

```
image = imread("a.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
```

Comment: thank you for response, since a.jpg it single channel grayscale, result is same.

Comment: @MMzztx No, when you use imread, it will load the image with BGR channels, in your case you used -1, which will also have alpha, but if you use CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE, it will load it into Mat image as a single channel image.  http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#Mat imread(const String& filename, int flags)

Comment: Thanks, so base on my understanding, -1 will return load image as what it is with alpha, and even if I use CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE, and I actually have tried it still will return the array as above in my question.

Comment: @MMzztx, jpeg is lossy, means it has compression artifacts, so next thing I would try is to make a pure black white image in paint, and save it to a loseless format, then load it with CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE.

Comment: using tif and png and CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE will just return all 0...that is weird cause on python no matter jpg,png or tiff they all return right pixel value