# imshow() producing weird results with OpenCV 3.2 in C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I am taking in RGB data from my Kinect and trying to put it into an OpenCV matrix. The data is held in "src":

```
Mat matrixImageRGBA(w, h, CV_8UC4);
memcpy(matrixImageRGBA.data, src, sizeof(byte) * w * h * 4);
```

However, when I use "imshow" to see the image, it is tiled four time horizontally. I am using the following command:

```
imshow("Window", matrixImageRGBA);
waitKey(500);
```

Does anyone have any idea of what the problem may be here? It's driving me nuts.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you getting the Kinect data? It sounds like it's not in the format you specified.

Comment: w and h are in the wrong order in the Mat constructor, if w is width and h is height. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25642532/opencv-pointx-y-represent-column-row-or-row-column/25644503#25644503 for possible reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `w` and `h` backwards. According to the docs the constructor takes the `height` as the first argument:

```
Mat (int rows, int cols, int type)
```

Also, I would recommend using this constructor:

```
Mat(int rows, int cols, int type, void *data, size_t step=AUTO_STEP)
```

instead of copying to the `data` field (since you are using no padding at the end of each row use the default `AUTO_STEP` for `step`).