# Segmentation fault while assigning a pixel value

Tags: c++, opencv

The following code results in a segmentation fault.

```
void sharpen(Mat& src, Mat& dst)
{
   cout<<"\n\nFunction just called\n\n";
   for (int i = 1; i < src.rows; i++)
   {
      for (int j = 1; j < src.cols; j++)
      {
         dst.at<uchar>(j, i) = 2*src.at<uchar>(j, i);
      }
   }

   imshow("src",src);
   imshow("dst",dst);
}
```

What is wrong with that?

Comment: Please provide more code, at least the loop for example. Also the declaration part would be useful.

Comment: My crystal ball says an off-by-one error. What does your debugger say?

Comment: `dst` and `src` may not be of the same size.

Comment: You swap rows and columns, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25644503/8051589). Use `dst.at<uchar>(i, j)=2*src.at<uchar>(i, j);`, Note the difference `(i, j)`. In the `Mat` class its `(row, column)` and in the `Point` class it's `(columns, row)`. Also observe what the other comments already said.

Comment: Also, are you sure that the `dst.at()` parameters are in column-major order (j, i) ? More often than not it can be the opposite (row-major i, j).

Comment: Thank you @AndreKampling I'd swapped the indices and added the line `Mat dst(src.rows,src.cols,src.type());` to make the dimensions equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You swap rows and columns, [see here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25644503/8051589). Use `dst.at<uchar>(i, j)=2*src.at<uchar>(i, j);`, note the difference `(i, j)`.

In the `Mat` class its `(row, column)` and in the Point class it's `(columns, row)`.

Also check your dimension of the matrices, because you are using the size of `src` for looping throught `src` and `dst`, so dimensions should be equal. Further start your index variable at `0` because in C/C++ you count from `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Dst and Source imgs must have the same size.
You can solve it by doing something like this

```
Mat sharpen(Mat src)

{

Mat dst = src.clone();
dst = 2*src;

imshow("src",src);
imshow("dst",dst);

return dst;


}
```