# how to write rectangle (bounding box) by xmax xmin ymax ymin using opencv

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.0, object-detection, bounding-box

I found that I cant easely write bounding box using 4 points (x, y, w, h) using opencv. Where x, y is top left corner and w=width, h=height.

`cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),15)`

But How is it possible to write bounding box using opencv having only **xmax xmin ymax ymin** points? I need to check that all is allright in my code and bounding boxes used by **x, y, w, h** is completely equal to bounding boxes that I have under **xmax xmin ymax ymin**.

I converted **x, y, w, h** to **xmax xmin ymax ymin** using these code

```
bbox_topleft_corner_x = int(prod_data[0])
bbox_topleft_corner_y = int(prod_data[1])
bbox_w = int(prod_data[2])
bbox_h = int(prod_data[3])

ymax = bbox_topleft_corner_y
ymin = bbox_topleft_corner_y - bbox_h
xmax = bbox_topleft_corner_x + bbox_w
xmin = ymin + bbox_w
```

But I'm not sure that I did all as I wanted. I wanted to convert **x, y, w, h** to **VOOC2007** annotation xml format and their bounding box format

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given x, y, width, and height, it should be trivial to get x_max and y_max.

```
x_max = x + width
y_max = y + height
```

It is important to remember the coordinate system for images starts with `(0, 0)` in the top left, and `(image_width, image_height)` in the bottom right. Therefore:

```
top_left = (x, y)
bottom_right = (x+w, y+h)
```

The last thing to remember is that there are some cases were the parameter requested is a point `(x, y)`, such as the case in the cv2.rectangle function. However, pixels are accessed as the underlying ndarray structure `image[row, column]`

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25642532/opencv-pointx-y-represent-column-row-or-row-column) for more info about opencv coordinate systems.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I got it. Coordinate system is so strange for me

Comment: Thanks, this is such an underrated question and answer.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your problem is the reference system.

In a image the point (0,0) is the top left pixel. Judging from your ymin calculation it seems you're considering y "the upper is the higher" but with an origin in top-left point is exactly the opposite.