# How to change value of all pixels in cv::Mat

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, opencv, matrix

I have a simple function that attempts to loop through all the pixels in a single channel cv::Mat. Its not functioning correctly. I'm running this in xcode on ios sim.

```
cv::Mat fillEdge(cv::Mat floated) {
    float currentColor = 255.0;
    cv::Size shape = floated.size();
    int h = shape.height;
    int w = shape.width;

    int count = 1;

    for(int y = 0; y!= h; y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x!= w; x++) {
            cv::Point2i p(y, x);
            floated.at<int>(p) = currentColor;
        }
    }
    std::cout << floated.channels() << std::endl;
    // prints 1


    std::cout << floated << std::endl;
    return floated;
}
```

For some reason it prints a striped image.

[image]
[image]

Here is what the output of the cv::Mat looks like before the function returns

```
[255,   0,   0,   0, 255,   0,   0,   0, 255,   0,   0,   0, 255,   0,   0,   0, 255,
0,   0,   0, 255,   0,   0,   0, 255,   0,   0,   0, 255,   0,   0,   0, 255,   0,
0,   0, 255,   0,   0,   0, 255,   0,   0,   0, 255,   0,   0,   0, 255,   0,   0,
0, 255,   0,   0,   0, 255,   0,   0,   0, 255,   0,   0,   0, 255,   0,   0,   ...
```

Comment: Is `p` defined somewhere else? Shouldn't it be defined as `cv:Point2i p = cv:Point2i(y,x)`?

Comment: Yes, I edited the question. It's defined right before the pixel changes value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I changed your `for` loops condition check, changed the definition of your `Point2i` and also changed the template type of your `at` method from `int` to `float`, to maintain type integrity.

This should work now:

```
cv::Mat fillEdge(cv::Mat floated) {
    float currentColor = 255.0;
    cv::Size shape = floated.size();
    int h = shape.height;
    int w = shape.width;

    int count = 1;

    for(int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            cv:Point2i p = cv:Point2i(x,y);
            floated.at<float>(p) = currentColor;
            //floated.at<float>(y,x) = currentColor; //You could also replace the two lines above with direct indexing (be careful with the order of the axis, as pointed by @Micka in the comments)
        }
    }
    std::cout << floated.channels() << std::endl;
    // prints 1


    std::cout << floated << std::endl;
    return floated;
}
```

Comment: p is wrong, it should be (x,y) order. Then you could use floated.at<float>(p), too. But with direct indexing it is in the right ordering floated.at<float>(y,x) which is usable, too.

Comment: Actually, in this case, declaration of `p`is useless. I put it that way just to denote how it should be declared in the first place, and then used direct indexing to show another way of using `.at`, not using points. But `p` should be declared as (y,x), as y (declared in the first loop) is ranging vertically (with height, not width), and the Point2i declaration is (row, column). Anyways, I'll update the answer.

Comment: no, points are (x=col,y=row) and have (x,y) ordering in the constructor. that's what I wanted to tell you. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/25642532/2393191

Comment: Oops, you're right! Thanks for the info!! Updated again!

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`setTo`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a0440e2a164c0b0d8462fb1e487be9876):

```
cv::Mat fillEdge(cv::Mat floated) {
    float currentColor = 255.0;
    floated.setTo(cv::Scalar(currentColor));
    return floated;
}
```

Comment: This will surely change the value of all pixels, but we lose control over each independent pixel. If we want to add an `if` statement in the inner `for` loop to apply a new color only to the edges (as the name of the function suggests), then the `.at()` method should be used.

Comment: @vini yes, of course. But the question explicitly asks for "all" pixels