# why should I use (y,x) instead of (x,y) to access a pixel in opencv?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv

I had to access a pixel into an image, using openCV but at first I wasn't able since python was telling me that the value I wanted to access was out of bound.

Then I searched for this error and I discovered that I should access a pixel using `image[y, x]` instead of `image[x, y]`.

I found this piece of information in the comments of this page, but there is no explanation:
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/01/opencv-center-of-contour/

> Adrian Rosebrock February 12, 2016 at 3:19 pm #:
>   When accessing pixel values in OpenCV + NumPy, you actually specify them in (y, x) order rather than (x, y) order. Thus, you need to use: image[cY, cX]

So, the question is...why should I invert the coordinates while trying to access a pixel?

Comment: Apart from Fortran, most languages store matrices in row-major order, so the indices are `row, column`, aka `y, x`.

Comment: OpenCV uses matrix notation for the images (in C++ is even call cv::Mat), this means `(row,column)`... However for Points they use cartesian coordinates, which it is `(x,y)`. It is a little confusing at the beginning

Comment: @PaulR thank you for giving a name to the problem!

Comment: I think it is because of matrix representation, since in opencv, images are represented as matrices: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25642532/opencv-pointx-y-represent-column-row-or-row-column/25644503#25644503

Comment: The very short answer is that you just have to live with it how they did it... along with the BGR rather than RGB channel ordering. I guess it's the price you pay for all that performance :-)

Comment: @Micka thank you for the explanation you gave. i'll look into it!

Comment: @MarkSetchell apparently yes, we can deal with it but we should be aware, which I wasn't!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find the answer in the comments. It is related to how a language store matrices:

> Apart from Fortran, most languages store matrices in row-major order,
>   so the indices are row, column, aka y, x. – Paul R Feb 6 at 8:30