# Why does cv::Mat ctor expect swapped size?

Tags: c++, opencv

> cv::Mat::Mat  (   Size    size,       int     type    )
>
> Parameters
>       size  2D array size: Size(cols, rows) . In the Size() constructor, the number of rows and the number of columns go in the reverse order.

[docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a75a97b1e4e55f380c172af58048a7cde)

I am reading a 4000x3000 image (verified via gimp), gdb reports a 4000x3000 frame. But when I create a `cv::Mat{ cv::Size{ 4000, 3000 } };`, the result is `f.rows == 4000; f.cols == 3000;`.

What's the advantage of designing the interface thus?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25642532/opencv-pointx-y-represent-column-row-or-row-column/25644503#25644503

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`cv::Mat`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a75a97b1e4e55f380c172af58048a7cde) is view as a matrix and it is accessed/created in the order you will do with a matrix, for example:

```
int rows = 4000, cols = 3000, type = CV_8U;
cv::Mat something( rows, cols, type, cv::Scalar::all(0));
something.at<uchar>(178 /*row*/, 928/*col*/) = 124;
```

In OpenCV there is more than cv::Mat, for instance cv::Point, which uses cartesian coordinates, i.e. x,y. In matrix notation speaking, the points are (col, row). And guess what, it can be also used with `.at` to specify a point, like this:

```
something.at<uchar>(cv::Point(928/*col*/,178/*row*/)) = 124;
```

We also have [`cv::Rect`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d2/d44/classcv_1_1Rect__.html), which is constructed with the top left point and bottom right point or with the top left point and the width and the height. In code it is something like:

```
cv::Rect r(10, 12, 100, 120);
// or in other words
cv::Rect r2(cv::Point(10,12), cv::Size(100, 120));
```

This `cv::Size` notation (width, height) is consistent with several other programs/os (like windows) where you can see the size specified as width x height (in your example 4000 x 3000).

Having said all this, you can see that OpenCV made itself quite flexible in the notations that can be used. Some people will stick with the matrix notations for cv::Mat and cartesian coordinates for Points and Rects, some other people prefer everything in cartesian... Why this decision? you better ask the creators of OpenCV, but I can tell you several other libraries does the same (see an image as a matrix and use matrix notation for it).

I hope this clears your doubts, but if not just leave a comment

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is more a question, why cols are before rows for the `cv::Size` contructor, while a `cv::Mat` constructor expects rows, then cols?

So this is one of those question, (y, x) or (x, y).
From a memory point the calculation works like `x+y*width`, so x should be first.

mathematicans on the other hand used to use (y, x) for centuries [wiki reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)).

Answer (score 0):

Hm, *cv::Mat{ cv::Size{ 4000, 3000 } }; works*? I doubt.

Try this ways:

```
cv::Mat img1(cv::Size(4000, 3000), CV_8UC3);
cv::Mat img2(3000, 4000, CV_8UC3);
```

They are really works.