# Unsure why I am getting a Index is Out of Bounds for Axis With Size Error with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, indexing, error-handling, index-error

I am doing some image processing within openCV, and am getting an index is Out of Bounds for Axis With Size Error.

I have tried adding in a

```
if(i+1 < len(img2) and j+1 < len(img2[0])):
```

to make sure we are in bounds within the array, but it just would skip each element of the array I believe.

I have tried removing the 0 and making it just a

```
for i in range(imgCol):
```

style loop.

I have also tried to reduce the length the array goes

```
for i in range(imgCol-1):
```

but the error persists.

Here is my current code.

```
img2 = cv2.imread('v2.jpg')

imgRow = img2.shape[0]
imgCol = img2.shape[1]

for i in range(0,imgCol):
    for j in range(0,imgRow):
        if ( img2[i,j,0] == 11 and img2[i,j,1] == 2 and img2[i,j,2] == 12):
            '''do something'''
```

Comment: the different between black and white and color is that in color there is 3 values, red. green, blue, could this give you the issue?

Comment: I take made a mistake, it seems like it errors either way. Not sure what was going on before then

Comment: run this: print( img2.shape[0]), the shape will not be what you expect

Comment: huh, your right. whats up with that? when i looked online people seemed to say this was the correct way to find the dimensions of your image, and go about looping through it.

Comment: if you do: print (img2.shape) what do you get?

Comment: im getting (203,293,3). The demension of the image when I check on my desktop is 200x273.

Comment: I think you just have the row/col reversed, your code runs on my image. do you have a url of your image to see if you still have the shape issue?

Comment: is in numpy the matrix index order really [col, row, channel]? in C++ openCV it is [row, col, channel] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25642532/opencv-pointx-y-represent-column-row-or-row-column/25644503#25644503

Comment: Woah, I think you guys are right. I need to do more testing, but that makes sense. Cant believe i didnt see that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is in this line:

```
if ( img2[i,j,0] == 11 and img2[i,j,1] == 2 and img2[i,j,2] == 12):
```

I think you are trying to go through each pixel and if its value is `(11, 2, 12)` then do something. An image is a 3 dimensional array, instead of accessing the value with `img2[i, j, 0]`, you may try `img[i][j][0]`.

---

Editting to summarize the comments:

- You may have the `row` and `col` reversed.
- Also another option to do for trouble shooting is to add a read flag `cv2.IMREAD_COLOR` to force OpenCV to read the image in BGR format, although this is the default.

Comment: Any change or the exact same errors? @Program232323

Comment: Exact same errors. It may be something to do with img2.shape[0]? But not entirely sure yet.

Comment: Is it possible that you got the `row` and `col` value reversed? @Program232323

Comment: @Program232323 What OS you are on and what's the OpenCV version? Also could you try one more thing: add a read flag `img2 = cv2.imread('v2.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)`

Answer (score 0):

when I run it like this (as UdonN00dle suggested) inverting rows and col, I get no error. I am not sure about your shape issue as I don't have your image

```py
#importing a random image
from PIL import Image
import urllib.request
import numpy as np

URL = 'http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg'

with urllib.request.urlopen(URL) as url:
    with open('temp.jpg', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(url.read())

img = Image.open('temp.jpg')

#the beginning of the code
img2 = np.asarray(img)


imgRow = img2.shape[0]
imgCol = img2.shape[1]
#inverted imgRow and imgCol
for i in range(0,imgRow):
    for j in range(0,imgCol):
        if ( img2[i,j,0] == 11 and img2[i,j,1] == 2 and img2[i,j,2] == 12):
            '''do something'''
```