# OpenCV subtract row/column mean from every pixel on every nth row/column

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a cv::Mat and I want to subtract the mean value of every 8th row (starting at 0, so 0, 8, 16 etc) from every pixel on that row.

Then I want to do the same with the columns.

For some reason, it's saying that every value on the first row is 0, when it clearly isn't.

Here's what I've tried:

```
    int N = 8;
    //cv::Mat row_mean, col_mean;
    //cv::reduce(myMat, row_mean, 0, CV_REDUCE_AVG); - not giving me what I want somehow?
    //cv::reduce(myMat, col_mean, 1, CV_REDUCE_AVG);

    for(int r = 0; r < myMat.rows; r = r + N)
    {
        float rowAvg = 0.0;
        for(int c = 0; c < myMat.cols; c++)
        {
            float val = myMat.at<float>(c, r);
            if (r == 0) {
                std::cout << "Row 0 val at " << c << " is " << val << std::endl;

            }
            rowAvg += val;
        }
        rowAvg /= myMat.rows;
        std::cout << "Actual mean at r " << r << " is " << rowAvg << std::endl;
        myMat.row(r) = myMat.row(r) - rowAvg;
    }

    for(int c = 0; c < myMat.cols; c = c + N)
    {
        float colAvg = 0.0;
        for(int r = 0; r < myMat.rows; r++)
        {
            colAvg += myMat.at<float>(c, r);            
        }
        colAvg /= myMat.cols;

        std::cout << "Actual mean at c " << c << " is " << colAvg << std::endl;
        myMat.col(c) = myMat.col(c) - colAvg;
    }
```

As you can see, I started by attempting to use reduce, but the values I got didn't seem right.

`myMat` has only two dimensions, it's worth clarifying.

**Update**
I worked out that when I pulled the average using reduce I was looking at the wrong dimensions. So I've fixed that, I think. So now it looks like this:

```
    cv::Mat row_mean, col_mean;
    cv::reduce(myMat, row_mean, 1, CV_REDUCE_AVG);
    cv::reduce(myMat, col_mean, 0, CV_REDUCE_AVG);

    for(int r = 0; r < myMat.rows; r = r + N)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < myMat.cols; c++)
        {
            myMat.at<cv::Vec3f>(r, c) = myMat.at<cv::Vec3f>(r, c) - row_mean.at<cv::Vec3f>(r, 0);
        }

    }

    for(int c = 0; c < myMat.cols; c = c + N)
    {
        for(int r = 0; r < myMat.rows; r++)
        {
            myMat.at<cv::Vec3f>(r, c) = myMat.at<cv::Vec3f>(r, c) - col_mean.at<cv::Vec3f>(0, c);
        }

    }
```

When I stdout the row_mean Mat it starts like this:

```
[0, 0.020882325, 0;
 0, 0.0043014521, 0;
 0, 0.0077573429, 0;
 0, -0.003039235, 0;
 0, 0.0094852885, 0;
...
```

And the col_mean one looks like this:

```
[0, 0.011529977, 0, 0, 0.017861091, 0, 0, -0.00044186518, 0, 0, 0.0062413695, 0, 0, 0.0060342439, 0, 0, 0.0068696449,...
```

So it seems as if (as Miki commented) there are three channels, but two are full of 0s.

The result still doesn't seem right. When viewing the values in a TIFF container it looks like adjacent rows and columns are somehow being affected, although that might be the container attempting to render it.

I just want to make sure that what I'm doing is now correct.

**Disclaimer**

I'm no c++ programmer!

Comment: `myMat.at<float>(c, r);` should be `myMat.at<float>(r, c);` Also, is it really a matrix of float?

Comment: I thought coordinates are x, y So wouldn't that be column then row?

Comment: No. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25644503/5008845

Comment: Thanks! I finally understand that bit. Makes sense. The Mat is indeed (I believe) type float (actually CV_32FC3)

Comment: if it's CV_32FC3, you should use myMat.at<Vec3f>(r,c). That also means that your image has 3 channels: you should probably operate separately on each channel

Comment: I've literally just worked that out about the channels. It's not an image, though. But yeah, it has three channels and two of them are all 0s

Comment: So when you say each channel..does that mean I can't say `myMat.row(r) -= row_mean.at<cv::Vec3f>(r, 0);` but instead have to look at each channel within that row?

Comment: Btw you can use this which works regardless o channels of image. This is less error prone. 
`const int N = 8;
    for(int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex<img.rows;rowIndex+=N)
    {
        Mat row = img.row(rowIndex);
        const auto rowMean = mean(row);
        row = row - rowMean;
    }`

Comment: @MuhammetAliAsan is `Mat row` a reference to `img.row` or a copy? I want it to change the original `img`...?

Comment: new copy of mat instance will share same data with the source. So modifying it will also modifiy original image.