# Discrepancy between cv::Mat::at and cv::minMaxLoc functions

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv-mat

I have a *cv::Mat* of type *CV_8U*. If I use the cv::minMaxLoc function like so:

```
cv::Mat img(rows, cols, CV_8U, data);

double minVal, maxVal;
cv::Point minLoc, maxLoc;

cv::minMaxLoc(img, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc);
```

I get:

> maxVal = 255, maxLoc = [127, 126]

Then if I  use the following code:

```
img.at<uint8_t>(maxLoc); //or img.at<uint8_t>(127,126);
```

> Result is 0

I actually get zero for every element of the matrix using both cv::Mat::at and cv::imshow(). But cv::minMaxLoc is giving the correct answer. So I was wondering if anyone had any insight as to why these two functions would not agree.

Comment: In `at` method first index means **row**, second one is **col**. Because `maxLoc` is point with `x = 127`, `y = 126`, so when calling `at` it should be: `img.at<uint8_t>(126,127)`.

Comment: You can also check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25642532/opencv-pointx-y-represent-column-row-or-row-column)