# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed / when visit the pixel of mat

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using OpenCV to try to calculate the sum of each pixel from a grayscale  picture.

```
cv::Mat dst;
dst = imread("dst.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
for (i = 0; i < dst.cols; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < dst.rows; j++)
    {
        dstSum += dst.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[0];
    }
}
```

And then the error comes:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dims <= 2 && data && (unsigned)i0 < (unsigned)size.p[0] && (unsigned)(i1*DataType<_Tp>::channels) < (unsigned)(size.p[1]*channels()) && ((((sizeof(size_t)<<28)|0x8442211) >> ((DataType<_Tp>::depth) & ((1 << 3) - 1))*4) & 15) == elemSize1()) in cv::Mat::at,

I googled this error message, it looks like I visit the pixel out of the matrix.

But I do have the `i < dst.cols` and `j < dst.rows` to make sure that situtation won't happen, right?

So what's the possible reason for this error...
Can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing two things wrong:

1. You image is grayscale (`uchar`), so you need to access it with `.at<uchar>(...)`
2. You are accessing the image as `(col, row)`, while the OpenCV (and any matrix-related) convention is `(row, col)`. You can also use mnemonics in your iteration: `r` and `c` for *row* and *col* respectively.

   ```
   for(int r=0; r<dst.rows; r++) {
       for( c=0; c<dst.cols; c++){
           dstSum += dst.at<uchar>(r, c);
       }   
   }
   ```

You can also improve your code a little:

1. You can use `Mat1b` and access it like `at(i,j)`

   ```
   Mat1b dst = imread(...);
   for(int r=0; r<dst.rows; r++) {
       for( c=0; c<dst.cols; c++){
           dstSum += dst(r, c);
       }   
   }
   ```
2. The new OpenCV name is `IMREAD_GRAYSCALE`:

   ```
   Mat1b dst = imread("path_to_image", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
   ```
3. You can use `cv::sum` to sum up all the pixels. The resulting improved code will be:

   ```
   Mat1b dst = imread("path_to_image", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
   int dstSum = sum(dst)[0]; // take only first channel
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
dst = imread("dst.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
```

You read the dst as a gray scale 8-bit image, that means each pixel have 1 channel, and 8-bit depth for this channel. So inside the loop should be

```
dstSum += dst.at<uchar>(i, j);
```

You can read more details [here.](http://ninghang.blogspot.com/2012/11/list-of-mat-type-in-opencv.html)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184053/accessing-elements-of-a-cvmat-with-atfloati-j-is-it-x-y-or-row-col), OpenCV uses a (row,col) indexation.

Try

```
for(i=0;i<dst.rows;i++){
    for(j=0;j<dst.cols;j++){
        dstSum += dst.at<uchar>(i, j);
    }
}
```

instead of your (col, row) indexation.