# OpenCV Segmentation fault (core dumped) While Using cv::Mat::at

Tags: c++, opencv, segmentation-fault, opencv3.2

I am trying to map `cv::Mat` pixels to `float4*` for CUDA computation.

```
cv::Mat frame = cv::imread("peds-007.png", cv::IMREAD_COLOR);

cudaAllocMapped((void**) cpu, (void**) gpu,
                frame.cols * frame.rows * sizeof(float) * 4);

float4* cpuPtr = *cpu;
for (uint32_t y = 0; y < frame.rows; y++) {
    for (uint32_t x = 0; x < frame.cols; x++) {
        std::cout << x << ", " << y << std::endl;
        const float4 px = make_float4(float(frame.at<cv::Vec3b>(x, y)[2]),
                                      float(frame.at<cv::Vec3b>(x, y)[1]),
                                      float(frame.at<cv::Vec3b>(x, y)[0]),
                                      float(255));
                                      //float(frame.at<cv::Vec4b>(x, y)[3]));         
        cpuPtr[y*imgWidth+x] = px;
    }
}
```

If I run the above code, I got `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

The last pixel accessed by the code is at (1662, 0).

If I directly access the pixel outside the loop:

```
frame.at<cv::Vec3b>(1662, 0);
```

It also causes `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

Why does this happen and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: what is `fr`? this condition is invalid: `x < fr`, it supposed to be `x < frame.columns`

Comment: @MarekR ah, yes. typo... thanks!

Comment: What is the resolution of your image?

Comment: So, did you see the answer?

Answer (score 1):

cv::Mat is indexed in row-major order. Reverse your x's and y's.

```
const float4 px = make_float4(float(frame.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x)[2]),
                              float(frame.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x)[1]),
                              float(frame.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x)[0]),
                              float(255));
```

Comment: You know this is weird... I just thought maybe the image was not loaded well so I tried `imshow` to see `Mat` through my eyes? Then it works... After `imshow`, it works... Weird...

Comment: I know y is the row index. You have the indexes reversed in the call to frame.at/. It's supposed to be y,x. Try it. See that it works. Mark this as the answer, and move Onward Through the Fog!

Comment: @GyuHyeon Choi - Are you still here? Could you please click on the green check-mark, above left?

Comment: The cv::Mat object is indexed in row-major order. The row comes first, then the column. Your y is the row. Thus the correct call is frame.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184053/accessing-elements-of-a-cvmat-with-atfloati-j-is-it-x-y-or-row-col#16635901

Comment: The reason you got the segmentation fault is that your image is not square. Therefore attempting to access it with col,row rather than the correct row,col, indexed the Mat out of range. It is easy to verify. I am at a loss as to what the communication problem is.

Comment: What are the dimensions of your image, in rows and columns?