# Why am I getting Undefined Behavior (EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1177c1530)) when I access a position of a matrix (opencv mat) on Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv, exc-bad-access, undefined-behavior

I am trying to develop a c++ program with opencv library on Xcode 9.3, macOS 10.14, using clang. During weeks I've been trying to solve or understand why I am getting an **undefined behavior error** that sometimes makes my program crash and sometimes not.

I am reading a set of images from different cameras and storing them in a multidimensional array: silC[camera][image]. (images are well stored)

I get this error **THREAD 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS** (code=1, address=0x1177c1530) when I do this: **currentImage.at(x,y)** even the values of currentImage are not the problem nor the image.

I post the code below if there's any chance someone could help me..

```
vector< vector<Mat> > silC(8,vector<Mat>());       // Store the pbm images separating from different cameras
```

*** I read the images and store them in silC. ***

```
for (int z=0; z < nz; z++) {
    for (int y=0; y < ny; y++) {
        for (int x=0; x < nx; x++) {        
            // Current voxel coordinates in the 3D space
            float xcoord = x*voxelsize + Ox + voxelsize/2;
            float ycoord = y*voxelsize + Oy + voxelsize/2;
            float zcoord = z*voxelsize + Oz + voxelsize/2;

            for (int camId=0; camId < matricesP.size(); camId++) {
                imgId = 0;
                currentImage = silC[camId][imgId];
                int w = silC[camId][imgId].cols;
                int h = silC[camId][imgId].rows;
                // Project the voxel from the 3D space to the images
                Mat P = matricesP[camId];
                Mat projection = P*(Mat_<float>(4,1) << xcoord,ycoord,zcoord,1.0);

                //We get the point in homog coord.
                float xp = projection.at<float>(0);
                float yp = projection.at<float>(1);
                float zp = projection.at<float>(2);
                // Get the cartesian coord                      
                int xp2d = cvRound(xp/zp);
                int yp2d = cvRound(yp/zp);

                if(xp2d >= 0 && xp2d < w && yp2d >= 0 && yp2d < h){
                    // all values are correct! :/

                    // int value = silC[camId][imgId].at<float>(xp2d, yp2d); // undefined behaviour: crashes sometimes.. 
                    int value = currentImage.at<float>(xp2d, yp2d); // undefined behaviour also crashes sometimes.. 
                    if(value == 255){
                        cout << "Voxel okey \n";
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:
The solution posted on comments below is that instead of currentImage.at(xp2d,yp2d) --> currentImage.at(yp2d,xp2d), as cv::Mat access requieres.

**BUT**, I tried to parallelize the for several times with openMP (*#pragma omp parallel for*) but it kept crashing. If someone is familiar with parallelize I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: What is the definition of `silC`? Did you happen to define it as a local variable?

Comment: [How to access opencv mat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184053/accessing-elements-of-a-cvmat-with-atfloati-j-is-it-x-y-or-row-col), `(xp2d, yp2d)` should be `(yp2d, xp2d)`

Comment: Have you checked `currentImage = silC[camId][imgId]` returns non-null? Should that be `ImagesC`?

Comment: yes! sorry, the code was a bit confusing before. I printed currentImage and it was not null. The thing is, sometimes the code works perfectly and sometimes it crashes at that line.

Comment: @rafix07 OMG.. I feel so stupid now. It seems to be working perfectly now. Thank you so much, sorry for my mistakes.

Comment: @rafix07 hey, when I try to parallelize the for with _#pragma omp parallel_ for, I still get the same error, are you familiar with these kind of orders?

Answer (score 0):

the solution is what @rafix07 posted. Thank you very much guys, next time I'll try to focus more.